# flutter: How to get access token from api to use it in header of another api Auth 2.0

Tags: flutter, api, postman

I am working on an app where i have an api to get access token and then i want to use that access token in header of another api to get authenticated. Auth 2.0 is used... i get the access token and access api in postman but i don't know how to do it in flutter.
please help

here is the code

```
     Future getToken() async {
        final uri = Uri.parse("https://.....");
        var requestBody = {
            "client_id": "clientid",
          "client_secret": "clientpassword",
          "redirect_uri": uri,
          "grant_type": "client_credentials"
        };
      
var response = await http.post(
          uri,
          body: json.encode(requestBody),
        );
    
        print(response.body);
      }
```

Comment: Please share request and response from Postman. Is the authorization server 3rd party service (which?) or custom implementation?

Comment: @user18309290 When i send request to post api.. I use token in authorization section from another api... then i'm able to send request otherwise i get error 401 unauthorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I assumed that you are trying to send access token in header of each api request for an example you can see below code you can store token in a variable from response and use that variable

```
     Future getToken() async {
        final uri = Uri.parse("https://.....");
        var requestBody = {
            "client_id": "clientid",
          "client_secret": "clientpassword",
          "redirect_uri": uri,
          "grant_type": "client_credentials"
        };
      
var response = await http.post(
          uri,
          body: json.encode(requestBody),headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $Token'
    };
        ),
    
        print(response.body);
      }
```

Comment: getting error that grant type is not specified

Comment: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The grant type was not specified in the request"}

Comment: I guess the error is coming from api please test it in postman once

Comment: It's working on post man and in Authorization section of post man i use access token generated by another API

Comment: ok fine in above answer I had used access token inside header section in postman now are you using bearer token?.....may I know the url in which you are using in postman

Comment: I had just updated the answer try adding Bearer infant of token

Comment: yes i am using bearer token

Comment: santosh.sports@gmail.com

Comment: if this answer is useful kindly accept my answer